# Is it possible to merge created stores in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So, my idea is to enhance an already created store with my own store...

A pseudo code would be something like this:

```
const store = createStore(reducer);
const myStore = createStore(reducer);

enhanceStore(store, myStore);
```

The purpose of this is that I'm creating a library that uses redux under the hood, today I'm configuring my own library store... But I wan't to be able to check if the user is already using redux, in that case I want to merge my store with his.

It's not mandatory to merge 2 stores, perhaps I can enhance the already created store with a new reducer...

Thanks!

Comment: Is it safe to assume to gave up on that idea to add new reducers to the existing store altogether or just found some workaround and forgot to update us, need something similar :)?

Answer (score 5):

I hope you're looking for [`store.replaceReducer()`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#replaceReducer)

> It is an advanced API. You might need this if your app implements code splitting, and you want to load some of the reducers dynamically.

Comment: Yeah, that's a possible solution, the main issue is that `replaceReducer` literally replaces all the reducers with a new one... I would like to just inject a new reducer inside the current store... This way I don't have to worry with the reducers that were already in there...

Comment: hey did you get any solution, working on similar use case

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you are after, but you can export the reducer from the `myStore`, and combine it with the `store`'s reducer.

```
combineReducers({
   ...
   myStoreApp: myStoreReducer
)}
```

If `myStore` has other important operations like complex initialization, you would have to manually merge those operations together with `store`'s initialization. Just note that the `myStore` state tree now lives under `myStoreApp` key

Comment: hmmm, I believe your example assumes that I have not initialized the store yet... So after combining all reducers I need I just call `createStore` with these merged reducers... The thing is that I want to inject a new reducer after `createStore` is called... Something similar to `store.replaceReducer`, but still not it :/

Comment: will this approach also pass the existing state values or will it clear them?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [@code-jaff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237916/8784518). **Please note that I assumed that you have your store creation in a central place.**

## Try this:

1. Define your common reducers
2. Create your store by calling `configureStore`
3. define a function called `injectReducer` and there try to replace the reducers with the new ones and also the common ones. We are gonna utilise `combineReducers` to do that.
4. **Use the `injectReducer` utility function in the `pages/_app.tsx` or `app/layout.tsx` if you have a nextjs app. or in your `App.tsx` if you're using a tool like vite/create-react-app. The main point is to use it in the most root level page to just add the extra reducer once to the redux store.**

## Example:

```
import {combineReducers, configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const commonReducers = { user: userReducer };
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: commonReducer,
  // ...
});
// export whatever you like, things like useTypedSelector, etc
export function injectReducer<T>(key: string, reducer: T) {
  store.replaceReducer(combineReducers({
    ...commonReducers,
    [key]: reducer
  }))
};
```